# access class name without using multiple parent methods

Tags: jquery, function, parent, closest

I am trying to find a cleaner way to access the "swatch-title-insert" div element without using the multiple parent methods shown in the function below. How can I write this better?

```
<!-- trying to access this element below in a cleaner way -->    
<div class="swatch-title-insert"></div>

<div class="carousel">
    <div class="jcarousel-clip">
        <ul class="product_swatch_list">
            <li class="product_swatch_list_item">
                <a href="http://www.test.com">
                    <span class="swatch_color" title="Green"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="product_swatch_list_item">
                <a href="http://www.test.com">
                    <span class="swatch_color" title="Blue"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>     

$('span.swatch_color').each(function(){     
    $(this).mouseenter(function(){
        var swatchColor = $(this);
        var swatchTitle = swatchColor.attr('title');
        var swatchTitleInsert = swatchColor.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().prev();
            swatchTitleInsert.html(swatchTitle);            
        });
});
```

Comment: use `.closest('.carousel').prev()` https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: Thank you. I was having trouble with closest() but makes total sense now that I access the previous element.

Comment: You are welcome :) Sometimes it is in your eyes, just skip it because tired, etc...